# Tiny font sizes in 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 (dual booted with Windows 10).

However the font sizes are absolutley tiny making it almost unusable.

Any sugestions?

Comment: In GNOME you can fix that with `gnome-tweak-tool`; I think there is a unity tweak tool or similar available

Comment: @Rmano. Thanks for the suggestion. It hasn't quite worked but it's definitely helped. It appears to be connected with the screen resolution and others have had a similar problem. I've had a whole host of minor but irritating problems with 16.04 and I now regret installing it.

Comment: Yes, me too. This is the reason why the new LTS is offered only when it reaches .1... frustrating. I have upgraded 4 different computers and the four of them had different show-stopping bugs. A normal user (I started managing unix systems in 1991) would have been simply stuck with an useless system. Sigh.